# Implementing a search function for a marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have Markers setup with gmaps4rails.

Now I want to implement a classic search function.

If I find one object, it should directly show the marker.infowindow

How do I open it directly?

I tried:

```
function focusSearch() {
            handler.map.centerOn({ lat: <%=@searchy.latitude %>, lng: <%=@searchy.longitude %>});
            handler.getMap().setZoom(16);
            marker = <%=@searchy.id%>
            marker.infowindow.open(map, marker.serviceObject);
      }
```

But I guess I am going wrong there...
Anyone can help?

If you have an Idea how to directly use the #search:params, I am happy!

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [a plunkr with working code here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/K7SzF54lchCHw1n1ph32?p=preview)

Basically steps are:

- associate the marker to the original json data where ids are available
- search the marker list for the id you expect
- trigger the 'click' google map event on the marker which triggers pan + infowindow

Comment: argh... One question from a js illiterate... How to integrate this plunkr with an <%=raw @hash.to_json %> query? thx again

Comment: Put it instead of the json

Comment: thx! that worked. Any chance you could tell me how to debug this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060151/gmaps4rails-doesnt-display-my-marker-until-reload