# Gmaps4rails doesn't display my marker until reload

Tags: gmaps4rails

I implemented a Gmaps4Rails Map in my app:

[Link to one Location, you may go back to the list with the link at the bottom and check another location ---](http://immosmap.herokuapp.com/locations/37)http://immosmap.herokuapp.com/locations/37

My problem ist that I get this error and it only displays a blue map:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setMap'

But when I reload, it does display the way I want it to work.

Do I have to implement a callback here? How? Didn't find my topic in the wiki...

Comment: Okay, I hacked it... I added the following JS:
'code'<script type="text/javascript">
 
if (location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1)
{
   location.href=location.href+'?reload';
 
}
 
</script>

But just doesn't feel right... Any better idea?

Comment: should be due to turbolinks but cant really tell without seing the code and the bug